# WebStorm doesn't stop at breakpoint when debugging ava tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, debugging, webstorm, ava

I have created an npm configuration to debug my ava tests in WebStorm (version 2017.2) following this [ava recipe here](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/debugging-with-webstorm.md). When I hit the debug button all tests are being ran but it doesn't seem to stop at any of the breakpoints. I also see bunch of these:

```
[?25l 
 ⠋ [?25l 
 ⠙ [?25l 
 ⠹  
 ⠸ [?25l[?25l 
 ⠼ [?25l 
 ⠴ [?25l
```

This is my npm debug configuration:
[image]

And this is the ava configuration in package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "ava",
  },
  "ava": {
    "files": [
      "test/lib/**/*.js"
    ],
    "source": [
      "app.js",
      "lib/**/*.js"
    ]
  },
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. 
What recipe doesn't say is, you still need to enable the inspector agent of Node.js by passing `--inspect-brk`. I put it there and now debugger stops at breakpoints and I can debug as usual.

Comment: You are putting this in the "Arguments" input? I am still not getting my breakpoints to break. (2017.3, in case it matters, and on Windows - it looks like you are on a Mac...)

Answer (score 1):

After adding the argument from @melis's answer here is the setup I'm using:

[image: screenshot of RubyMine]